# Jersey MediaType nullpointer exception

Tags: android, jersey-client

My Android app gives out this exception, I dont know what I am missing here.

```
08-10 09:55:19.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 09:55:19.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18502):    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
08-10 09:55:19.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18502):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.PartialRequestBuilder.type(PartialRequestBuilder.java:92)
08-10 09:55:19.919: E/AndroidRuntime(18502):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.type(WebResource.java:347)
```

Exception at >>>>

```
@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);

        URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(getURL()).build();
        WebResource service = client.resource(url);

    >>> return service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(getResponseType());
    }
```

Comment: log cat says error on the function `at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)` and the line you show doesn't contain `valueOf` function. please verify your log again.

Comment: the exception line after shows my code and the line which i have pointed out..

Comment: whats `getResponseType()` contains ?

Comment: thanks my method.. it returns a Class `public abstract Class<?> getResponseType();`

Comment: so that's the cause of your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON is  null.

you can use LogCat to print the value of MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.

check APPLICATION_JSON from where